# Importing multiple CA in truststore with same CN name but different alias

Tags: java, ssl, ca, truststore

In one of my servers I have imported 2 CA's having the same CN name with different aliases in the trustore.

The above is required because the signature of the CA got changed, so in order to support both old and new device SSL communication I need to
have both CA's in my trustore

Now the problem is only one of the devices with the old CA is passing the **SSL** communication.

When I add both the CA's in cacerts file then my new device is passing the ssl communication and old one is failing (because it is not validating it against other CA).

So now I want to know why we have 2 different behaviors when CA's are imported in truststore vs cacerts file.

Also how can I handle this situation and make it work. (I do not have any option to generate a new CA with different CN name so that option is not in scope)

Comment: Do the CAs have a comon signer further up the chain? In that case you only need the certificate of the common signer, not both CA certificates.

Comment: Please provide more information - e.g. example of certificate CN and path to issuing CA. There is more than just the CN at play here.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is the case for virtual host.

You have:

https://host-1.**company-A**.com/app-1 that works.

Now company-A was merged into company-B and you still need to support both. And you need to support both with the same Tomcat deployment (eventually it is the same application):

https://host-1.**company-B**.com/app-1

So you need 2 virtual hosts on the same host-1. Each virtual host with his own certificate and alias. Each certificate has different CA chain.

Read more about [Tomcat virtual host here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) and [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/host.html).

Another simpler option is to use host aliases that will reference several domains to a single context. Read [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/host.html#Host_Name_Aliases).

Comment: This is exactly what he already has, except that of course he doesn't have two identical truststore, and he has already stated that it doesn't work. Please read the question.

Comment: Actually there is an old book explaining virtual hosting here: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781849516624/11/ch11lvl1sec01/virtual-hosting . Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are suggesting there is something behind that paywall that suggests you need two identical truststores, please post an apposite quotation so we can all see it: and if you are a beneficiary of this paywall you should disclose it. Hope this helps. I suggest a less condescending attitude in future posts :-|

Comment: @user207421: yes the final root certificate is same but adding only root certificate does not work.

Also the scenario is: 
This is for 1st client:
Client Certificate (A) --> Intermediate Certificate (I) --> Root Certificate (R)
For Second Client:
Client Certificate (B) --> Intermediate Certificate (I_New) --> Root Certificate (R)

Now Here Intermediate Certificate (I) and I_New are exactly same (Same Common name) but with different signature.

Hence i need to import both the intermediate certificate in my single truststore.

Hope this helps to understand query better.